# i7-12700K inexplicably turning off p-cores periodically for long running tasks

Tags: cpu, performance, windows-11, multi-core

I like to run lots of heavy computation on my computer (like factoring large integers and other computational number theory), and my 17-12700K is usually pretty good at it.

But sometimes the task manager shows that the the p-cores will stop running the program and "dump" them to the e-cores, which then locks up my computer as (I assume) there isn't enough CPU power to run the heavy task and the operating system at full speed.

It usually doesn't lock up irrecoverably, but this is annoying and slows down progress for seemingly no reason. It doesn't interrupt the correctness of the program, doesn't seem to be a heat issue, and seems to happen regardless of restart time or number of threads used.

I can only assume it's happening due to some senseless "optimization" that silently attempts to throttle long running processes by moving them to e-cores when their total power usage gets too high (which I'm fine with). But I want the process to remain IDLE priority so it doesn't interrupt my more active tasks. [image: image of a task manager window next to a hwinfo window showing 16 p-cores of computation getting squished into 4 e-cores with no heat issues causing it]

Anybody have any idea what might be going on and how I might be able to remedy it? It will stay like this for arbitrary amounts of time, wasting computer cycles: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't able to figure out why exactly this was happening, but to work around it, I was able to use the software [Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/) to set the processor affinity for the affected processes to exclude the e-cores entirely. And this has the added benefit of ensuring that the OS always has some e-core cycles to keep things responsive.